# Want to get the dynamic facebook page access token using facebook page id

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Right now I am able to get the access token for our own page but not able to retrieve the page access token for others.
Below API I am using for get the review for our own page.
https://graph.facebook.com/page-id?fields=id&access_token=xxx
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only get Page Tokens for Pages you own, and you can only get Reviews/Ratings of Pages you own.

Comment: Is there any way to get a Reviews/Ratings of any facebook public page?

Comment: As I have to show the facebook page  Reviews/Ratings on my website

Comment: no, there is no way. as you can read in my answer, you can only get reviews/ratings of pages you own.